# ECS Task keeps throwing erorr "DockerClientConfigError: unable to get BridgeIP for task in bridge mode"

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, fluentd

[ECS Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3ak1.png)
Using AWS ECS, I'm deploying two services. The first service is my frontend service (Replica) and the second service is a fluentbit log driver (DAEMON). The frontend service has never had an issue and comes up like it should, passing all health checks etc..However, when I deploy either another task definition in the same service, or a separate service all together with it's own task defintion, I get the error "Status reason DockerClientConfigError: unable to get BridgeIP for task in bridge mode"

There isn't an issue of a NAT gateway not being present or anything here..I can login to the EC2 host and do updates, pull packages, etc..Here is a snippet of my cloudformation template which shows how I'm setting up the services.

```
service:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    DependsOn: 
      - ALBListener
      - ECSAutoScalingGroup
    Properties:
      Cluster: !Ref 'ECSCluster'
      LaunchType: EC2
      ServiceName: vrs-client-test-service
      DeploymentController: 
        Type: ECS
      DesiredCount: 4
      PlacementStrategies:
        - Field: instanceId
          Type: spread
      LoadBalancers:
      - ContainerName: vrs-client-test
        ContainerPort: 443
        TargetGroupArn: arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:<acctnumber>:targetgroup/vrs-client-test-container/e0fee39950d680ec
      TaskDefinition: !Ref 'taskdefinition'
      ServiceRegistries:
        - RegistryArn: !GetAtt DiscoveryService.Arn
          ContainerName: vrs-client-test
          ContainerPort: 443
taskdefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      Family: !Join ['', [!Ref 'AWS::StackName', -vrs-client-test]]
      ContainerDefinitions:
      - Name: vrs-client-test
        Essential: true
        Image: <acctid>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/vrs-client:sha.df4f418f
        Cpu: 256
        Memory: 512
        PortMappings:
          - ContainerPort: 443
            HostPort: 0
fluentservice:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    Properties:
      Cluster: !Ref 'ECSCluster'
      LaunchType: EC2
      ServiceName: vrs-client-fluentbit
      DeploymentController:
        Type: ECS
      SchedulingStrategy: DAEMON
      TaskDefinition: !Ref 'taskdefinitionfluent'
taskdefinitionfluent:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      Family: !Join ['', [!Ref 'AWS::StackName', -vrs-client-test-fluent]]
      ContainerDefinitions:
      - Name: log_router
        FirelensConfiguration:
            Type: fluentbit
            Options:
              enable-ecs-log-metadata: true
        Essential: true
        Image: 906394416424.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/aws-for-fluent-bit:latest
        Memory: 100
        LogConfiguration:
          LogDriver: awsfirelens
          Options:
           Port: "443"
            tls: 'on'
            tls.verify: 'off'
            Format: "json_lines"
```

Comment: Have you found any solution yet? I'm seeing the same error for a similar situation. I have an example task definition running for a service. And when I try to update it with another task definition, I see `unable to get BridgeIP for task in bridge mode`

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing the same error with a task definition. It had my app container, and a Fluent-bit container. The Fluent-bit container was configured to mount a volume from the app container. So ECS was trying to start the app container first.

Someone pointed me this AWS doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/using_firelens.html

> For tasks that use the bridge network mode, the container with the FireLens configuration must start before any application containers that rely on it start. To control the start order of your containers, use dependency conditions in your task definition. For more information, see Container dependency.

> Note: If you use dependency condition parameters in container definitions with a FireLens configuration, ensure that each container has a START or HEALTHY condition requirement.

So to implement this,

1. I reversed the dependency by having the App container mount the volume from the Fluent-bit container.
2. Also, I used the dependency configuration to enforce that the Fluent-bit container starts before the App container.

Now the task definition is running perfectly!

Also, my earlier setup (with Fluent-bit container depending on the app container) was working fine with **Network mode = awsvpc**

When I switched the Network mode to **bridge**, I started getting the `unable to get BridgeIP` error.